# exists statement not working perl

Tags: perl, exists

This is a homework assignment. I am not looking for the "code to make it work" more looking for a point in the right direction on where my logic is wrong.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#rot13 sub for passwords
sub rot13{
    my $result;
chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);``
# all has to be lower case
my $lower = lc $input;
my $leng = length $lower;

for(my $i = 0; $i < $leng; $i++){

        my $temp = substr ($lower,$i,1);
        my $con = ord $temp;

        if($con >= '55'){
                if($con >= '110'){
                        $con -= 13;
                }
                else{
                        $con += 13;
                }
        }
    $result = $result . chr $con;
}
return $result;
};
#opening a file specified by the user for input and reading it
#into an array then closing file.
open FILE, $ARGV[0] or die "cannot open input.txt";
my @input = <FILE>;
close FILE;

my (@username,@password,@name,@uid,@shell,@ssn,@dir,@group,@gid);
my $ui = 100;
foreach(@input){
my ($nam, $ss, $gro) = split ('/', $_);
chomp ($gro);
$nam= lc $nam;
```

I created a hash so I can use the exists function then using the function and if it does exist go to the next round of the loop. I feel like I am missing something with this.

```
my %nacheck;
if( exists ($nacheck { '$nam' } )){
    next;
}
$nacheck{ "$nam" } = 1;



while (my ($key, $value) = each %nacheck){
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

All this works for now but any tips on how to do it better would be appreaciated

```
my($unf, $unm, $unl) = split (/ /, $nam);
$unf = (substr $unf,0,1);
$unm = (substr $unm,0,1);
$unl = (substr $unl,0,1);
my $un = $unf . $unm . $unl;

if(($gro) eq "faculty"){
    push @username, $un;
    push @gid, "1010";
    push @dir, "/home/faculty/$un";
    push @shell, "/bin/tcsh";
}
else{
    my $lssn = substr ($ss,7,4);
    push @username, $un . $lssn;
    push @gid, "505";
    push @dir, "/home/student/$un";
    push @shell, "/bin/bash";
} 
    #pushing results onto global arrays to print out later  
push @ssn, $ss;
my $pass = rot13;
push @password, $pass;
push @name, $nam;
push @uid, $ui += 1;
}
#printing results
for(my $i = 0; $i < @username; $i++){
print      
"$username[$i]:$password[$i]:$uid[$i]:$gid[$i]:$name[$i]:$dir[$i]:$shell[$i]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've written it:

```
my %nacheck;
if( exists ($nacheck { '$nam' } )){
    next;
}
$nacheck{ "$nam" } = 1;
```

the `%nacheck` is newly created and must be empty. Therefore the `exists` test fails.

Or have you just shown the definition adjacent to the test for the purpose of the example?

If so, can you show us what your code actually looks like?

*Edit:* Also, as Charles Engelke noted, you've used single-quotes around a variable `'$nam'` which is wrong.

Comment: That's all of it. I wanted to create a hash just so I could run the exists test because in this case the first time around there is no chance of a repeat. So in my mind it comes back as a fail and runs the rest of the loop where it the hash gets added too in the first line. I only want it not to fail if there is a name that matches in it so it will move to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: The line `my %nacheck` creates a new, empty hash so the `exists` test in the next statement must always fail as nothing has been added to the hash yet.  If you have this in a loop, then you need to place the `my %nacheck` outside the loop.

Comment: WOW.. Thanks so much I have been staring at this for so long and that never even went through my mind. Thanks again works perfect now!

Answer (score 4):

The value of the expression '$nam' is those four characters themselves. The value of the expression "$nam" is whatever the value of the variable $nam is, expressed as a string.

Double quotes allow string interpolation. Single quotes do not; you get exactly what you type.

Comment: Yeah I originally had double quotes but it was not working then either so I was trying different things.

Comment: If you use the value of a variable as a hash key, you almost *never* have to quote that variable.